# Redirect User to previous page after successful login in django all auth

Tags: django, django-allauth

I'm using django allauth in my project, it is working fine, but I'm facing little bit issue, that is user didn't redirect to previous page after successful login. I tried to search on google but i din't find any solutions.

Comment: Please elaborate more, what do you mean by previous page? Is it mean home or dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Most login pages support getting the redirect URL from the 'next' query string parameter. If using a LoginRequired mixin or decorator, this is done automatically by default.

If you're doing it manually, you should just need to add it to the query string yourself when doing your redirect or in your link URLs.